# How to get version number and then compare it to minimum

Tags: bash, shell

I am using this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285924/how-to-compare-a-programs-version-in-a-shell-script) to compare the min version number that is required. But before i go to comparison, I am actually stuck on how to extract the version number.

My current script looks like this

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=`pgsync -v`

echo "---"
echo $x
```

and its output is

```
> ./version-test.sh
0.6.7
---
```

I have also tried with `x="$(pgsync -v)"` and i am still getting an empty string. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: This is what package managers are for. Don't test it at runtime; let it fail if you haven't installed it properly.

Comment: agree but it is kind of requirement from higher up. that its better to test for specific version before letting the script do partial things.

Comment: Looks like `pgsync -v` writes to standard error, not standard output. Some redirection is probably needed.

Comment: @User123, `rpm`?

Comment: @Shawn: how did you figure out that its writing to `stderror`? i was able to extra version number after your comment. i used this `x=$(pgsync -v 2>&1 > /dev/null)`

Comment: Not sure if `> /dev/null` is needed.

Comment: By looking at the output of your script that you provided. The pgsync output appearing above the dashes was a big hint.

Comment: @EmAe - short of knowing what to look for (per Shawn's comment) ... `pgsync -v 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt` and then see which file contains what output

Comment: @Shawn: Can you write the answer so that i can accept. The final code looks like this `pgsync_current_version=$(pgsync -v 2>&1)`. @markp-fuso I don't want to save it to a file.

Comment: @EmAe, The intent was to show which gets printed where and not *save it in a file*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to capture a command's output in a variable and it's instead getting printed to the terminal, that's a sign the command isn't writing to its standard output, but to another stream - usually standard error. So just redirect it:

```
x=$(pgsync -v 2>&1)
```

As an aside, writing out an explicitly requested version number to standard error instead of standard output is counter intuitive and arguably a bug.

Also, prefer `$()` command substitution to backticks; see [Bash FAQ 082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for details.